# SQL using subqueries instead of join for one to many

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, db2

I am trying to create a select that will allow me to join two tables together without using any operation that uses JOIN. The catch is that these two tables contain a one to many relationship.

Let's say there are two tables, Department and Course.

Department
D_CODE  | SCHOOL
 
01             | 1111

02             | 1111
03             | 2222
Course

CRS_CODE | D_CODE
MATH1           | 01
MATH2           | 02
ACCT1           | 03

How do I find all schools and the total number of courses it provides without using any type of join?

The result is that School 1111 has 2 courses and School 2222 has 1 course.
I've tried using WITH and multiple subqueries, but the resulting values always duplicates. So it will say School 1111 has 16 courses and School 2222 has 16 courses (as an example).

Guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Without using `sub-query` in `Where condition` also you will get the same result.

```
SELECT Count(D_CODE) No_OF_Course,
       SCHOOL
FROM   Department
WHERE  D_CODE IN(SELECT D_CODE
                 FROM   course)
GROUP  BY SCHOOL
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can avoid sub queries and explicit joins:
Use SELECTS over multiple tables (some kind of implicit join). This Code is not tested but will probably work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course, department WHERE course.D_CODE = department.D_CODE
```

Edit: a commenter claims this statement is wrong and sounds reasonable about it:
You know subqueries are very expensive and will kill your database server performance? Use joins when possible.

Comment: Gosh, I didn't know that subqueries are very expensive and will kill database server performance.  Can you provide a reference for that?  (There are situations where they do have poor performance; there are other cases where they may generate the most efficient query plan.)

Comment: My professor in university said this. Each subquery is executed each time a query does a check in worst case. Example: SELECT user FROM users WHERE users.posts > (SELECT AVERAGE(posts) FROM users). Average is performed on each single entry in the table user. So by 1000 users it is done 1000 times. For 1 query. I don't know 1 case where subquery speed things up. But that doesn't mean that there is such a case ;). It is just what I learned in university 5 or 6 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately, I am required to find a solution without using any join operation. It currently doesn't seem feasible without using the implicit join (WHERE __ = ___ )

Comment: @stupidstudent . . . Your professor is wrong.  YOu should learn more about databases and how optimization engines work, especially before you make unfounded claims.

Comment: I am sorry if I spread wrong claims. Thank you for the correction :). Can you please provide me with a good link or some good keywords for a google search to this topic?