# Added new columns to table and slow down the whole database .. Why?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got a table `USERDATA` and I added few new columns to it.
All are NOT NUL and default 0 or 1. However, my website became slow after doing that.
I mean really slow. And it's because of this query script on my website:

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 50 IDNum, IDName, Nation, (SELECT SUM(Loyalty) FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority = 1) as ClanLoyalty, (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority = 1) as ClanManner FROM KNIGHTS WHERE KNIGHTS.IDNum NOT IN (1,15001) ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, IDName ASC');
```

It worked all good previously but after adding the new columns which are not included at all in this query above .. it still slow down the website to request TOP 50 .. basically the `SUM` query is doing it .. why these new columns could produce such a problem?

`USERDATA` has 32k rows only and it worked all good previously. I didn't specify constaint, could be this the issue?

**I use MSSQL Server 2005.**

Comment: can you convert not in to in ?
@NoDisplayName query can produce different plan might be much better than your query.
can you share schema of underling table with execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this.

```
SELECT TOP 50 IDNum,
              IDName,
              Nation,
              Sum(Loyalty)     ClanLoyalty,
              Sum(MannerPoint)  ClanManner
FROM   KNIGHTS
       LEFT JOIN USERDATA
              ON USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum
                 AND USERDATA.Authority = 1
WHERE  KNIGHTS.IDNum NOT IN ( 1, 15001 )
Group by IDNum,IDName,Nation
ORDER  BY ClanLoyalty DESC,
          IDName ASC
```

Comment: You can look at discussion here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007413/sql-using-subqueries-instead-of-join-for-one-to-many/27007471#27007471

Comment: @RADAR Agreed, but still OP used the same Sub-query twice which can be removed

Comment: Still it's super slow. However, I tested it and it's caused by the new columns I added but weird part is that these are not even included into this query. The only this is that it grabs data from USERDATA where the new columns are. What may cause this? Probably I need to edit these columns. Is it because bigint is bugged in MSSQL Server 2005 or what I should try ? Please give me any point to check since I am really nervous that I cant fix it....